# libvirt-bin.conf file missing

Tags: virtualization, openstack, kvm-virtualization

So recently I'm working on Opnestack live-migration

I followed [this guide](https://www.mirantis.com/blog/tutorial-openstack-live-migration-with-kvm-hypervisor-and-nfs-shared-storage/) to setup my environment and in one of the configuration step I need to modify both `/etc/init/libvirt-bin.conf` and `/etc/default/libvirt-bin` file but I couldn't find these 2 files in my system.

I've tried `apt-get install libvirt-bin` and it said it is already the newest version.
I also tried `service libvirt-bin start` but nothing happened.

Just wondering did I miss something here or the tutorial is a little too old(Oct. 2013) and libvirt has changed a lot ?(though I don't think so)

Thanks for the help .

Comment: You can look at `dpkg -L libvirt-bin` to see the list of files that should have been installed. And you can test if the service has been started through `service libvirt-bin status`. This might give more information. Did you install from a ppa instead of the default ubuntu repositories? What is the version of your Ubuntu?

Comment: dpkg result : http://imgur.com/1QMqzNP  
It seemed it didn't install successfully compared to another computer with libvirt-bin running on it. I didn't change anything about ppa so I assume I installed from default ubuntu repo and my ubuntu version is 16.04

Comment: So it's best to uninstall, clear the cache and install again: `sudo apt-get remove libvirt-bin`, which will probably remove some other packages as well, then `sudo apt-get clean` and after that `sudo apt install libvirt-bin`as well as the other packages removed in step 1.

Comment: What I do not understand: Your package content as shown in your image differs heavily from the official list at https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/xenial/amd64/libvirt-bin/filelist. Try to find out from which source you got the package.

Comment: It seemed I have the latest version of libvirt-bin(2.5.0-3ubuntu5.2~cloud0) installed with my `apt-get install libvirt-bin` and in this version libvirt-bin becomes a virtual package. (ref : https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt). So I should either downgrade my libvirt-bin(though there might be lots of package dependencies problem) or find out whether there's another way to setup the environment.

Comment: Where did you get `2.5.0-3ubuntu5.2`? It is officially not in the 16.04 repositories, but in zesty (17.04). Ifyou really need this version, The page you referenced says for `libvirt-bin`: "This is a transitional package. You can safely remove it.".  I will try to find out what installation is needed for that version.

Comment: After installing zesty `libvirt-bin`was the same small package as yours. The configuration now seems to be done in `/etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf`, `/etc/default/libvirtd`and the service defined as `/etc/init.d/libvirtd` and started with `service libvirtd start`. The link you provided seems a bit outdated; you'll have to experiment with the places to configure. Try the two configuration files mentioned. And try to find out, which `libvirt-bin` version is on `scopelab` and why the package contents differ.

Comment: I use `dpkg -s libvirt-bin` to check and the `libvirt-bin` verison on `scopelab` is `2.5.0-3ubuntu5` with many Conffiles rather than `2.5.0-3ubuntu5.2` with no Conffiles on another computer. I'll try to configure the files you mentioned first and see if it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party ... but ... libvirt has actually changed quite a bit. Especially between Ubuntu 12.04 and 16.04. I had a similar problem after manually upgrading libvirt, I couldn't find libvirt-bin.conf to add `-l` flag for listening to tcp.

It turns out that the configuration file path is now at `/etc/default/libvirtd` instead of `/etc/default/libvirt-bin`.
Finally, you can invoke `systemctl restart libvirtd` or `service libvirtd restart` to restart libvirt

Answer (score 0):

1. Use config file  /etc/default/libvirtd and enable -l

#options passed to libvirtd, add "-l" to listen on tcp

libvirtd_opts=" -l "

2. Modify /etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf.

   listen_tls = 0

   listen_tcp = 1
3. Restart Libvirtd
   Libvirt  is listening on port 16509

$ netstat -lntp | grep libvirtd

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:16509           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      38482/libvirtd
tcp6       0      0 :::16509                :::*                    LISTEN      38482/libvirtd